# Unable to copy data from external table to exact copy of external table

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, external-tables

While building a test DB environment in a SQL Azure DB, I dynamically generate a new DB using CREATE TABLE scripts generated from an originating, prototype DB.

Some of these tables require data from the prototype DB so for each of these I create an external table (referencing the table in the prototype DB) and then run an INSERT INTO query which takes data from the external table and inserts it into the exact copy in the test DB.

The important point here is that both the new table and the external table are dynamically generated using a script which is built in the prototype DB; the new table and the external table should therefore be exact copies of that in the prototype DB.

However, for one of these tables, I ran into an exception

> Large object column support is limited to only nvarchar(max) data type.

The table in question didn't have anything greater than NVARCHAR (MAX) (such as TEXT), though it did have 10 NVARCHAR (MAX) columns. So I altered these columns to NVARCHAR (4000) and ran the process again.

I now encounter the following exception:

> The data type of the column 'my_column_name' in the external table is different than the column's data type in the underlying standalone or sharded table present on the external source.

I've refreshed and checked the column type in the prototype DB, the external table and the new table, and all of these show that the data type is NVARCHAR (4000).

So why does it tell me that the data type is different?

Is it a coincidence that the column was previously NVARCHAR (MAX)?

Comment: I received the same error when trying to bring over an nvarchar column from a pre-existing view in  my master DB. All other data types come over fine, but not nvarchar. And I cannot modify the source data type.